# CSS Animation - Is there a way to make the animation less jittery?

Tags: css, sass

So I am using a CSS animation to bounce around text but it seems that the animation is quite jittery, is there any way to make this run any smoother?

Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="x">
  <p class="y">TEST</p>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
$size: 100px;

body {
  margin: 0;
}

img, div {
  width: $size;
  height: $size;
}

.x {
  animation: x 3s linear infinite alternate;
}

.y {
  font-size: 35px;
  animation: y 4s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes x {
  100% {
    transform: translateX( calc(100vw - #{$size}) );
  }
}

@keyframes y {
  100% {
    transform: translateY( calc(100vh - #{$size}) );
  }
}
```

[And here is the link to the CodePen.](https://codepen.io/silvawebdesigns2020/pen/RwGzagV)

Comment: Its already least jittery, what do you want more?

Comment: @Kaustubh - Can you not see that it isn't very smooth? You can see at times it doesn't go around the screen as smooth as I would expect it to do...

Comment: No jitters on my laptop (Windows 10/Edge) - GPU is being used between 9%-12%, main CPU hardly at all. Seems fine to me. What browser and what hardware/OS are you using? (Also no jitters on iPad IOS 14 Safari).

Comment: @nsilva it is working perfectly fine. It depends on processing and storage most of the time so try refreshing your system and open the same in an incognito tab